# mysql command line with MAMP

Tags: macos, mamp

I realized I couldn't install mysql workbench on my macosx 10.5.8 and I had no other solution but to use mysql command line on the operating system. Here is how I started to use mysql command line on MAMP if anyone found that useful I'm answering my own question to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
    cd /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin

then issue

    ./mysql -u root -p

Enter password: 

mysql>
```